# CakePHP3 'contain' doesn't retrieve 'belongsTo'

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

A user has multiple products. Each product has a brand.

In the Products Table, I have a "brand_id" column.

For the moment there is no join when I do `debug($user)`.

I would like a join between Brands and Products Tables `(product.brand_id = brand.id)`. How can I solve this ?

(sorry for my english)

```
//Controller Users
    $users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('users');
    $user = $users->find('all')
            ->contain(['Products' => ['conditions' => ['id' => 25]]])
            ->first();
    debug($user); 


//Model Users
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->hasMany('products');
}


//model Products
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->belongsTo('brands');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
->contain([
   'Products' => ['conditions' => ['id' => 25]],
   'Products.Brands', // Add product brands
])
```

read more: **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations**